# Solution to the differential-integral equation $f(x)^3 = x^2 f'(x) \int_0^x f(t) \ \mathrm dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a method to solve the following differential-integral equation?

$$
f(x)^3 = x^2 f'(x) \int_0^x f(t) \ \mathrm dt \text.
$$

I know that $f(x) = \frac{2 x^2}{3}$ satisfies the equation, but I am looking for a generalized solution (without guess and verify).

Comment: Let $u=\int_0^xf(x)dx$. We can transform this equation into a ODE. $uu''x^2=(u')^3,u(0)=0$. However, it's difficulty, since it's nonlinear.

Answer (score -1):

if you let:
$$g'(x)=f(x)$$
then you have:
$$g'(x)^3=x^2g''(x)\left[g(x)-g(0)\right]$$
if we assume that $g(0)=0$ we get:
$$g'(x)^3=x^2g''(x)g(x)$$

letting $g(x)=ax^n$ gives:
$$(anx^{n-1})^3=x^2\cdot n(n-1)ax^{n-2}\cdot ax^n$$
this leaves us with:
$$3n-3=2n,\,a^3n^3=a^2n(n-1)$$
so:
$$n=3,a=\frac{n-1}{n^2}=\frac29$$
and so:
$$g(x)=\frac29x^3\Rightarrow f(x)=\frac23x^2$$

Comment: This finds monomial solutions only, how would you go about showing differentiable solutions?